# "The LinkedList node does not belong to current LinkedList"

Tags: powershell, collections, linked-list, hashtable

I've run into a wall while trying to understand how to insert hashtables into LinkedLists. I lost count of different things that I tried. I know I could use ArrayList or something else, but I wanted to make this work with LinkedLists so that I could benchmark it...

This is what I've come up with:

```
#BEGIN SAMPLE SCRIPT
#------------------------
$list = New-Object Collections.Generic.LinkedList[Hashtable] 

For($i=1; $i -lt 10; $i++){
   $list.AddLast(@{ID=$i; X=100+$i;Y=100+$i}) 
} 

ForEach($item In $list){ 
   If($Item.x -eq 105){ 
       $list.AddAfter($item, @{ID=128;X=128;Y=128}) 
       Break
   } 
}  

ForEach($item In $list){
   write-host "ID:"$item.ID", X:"$item.x", Y:"$item.y", TYPE:" $item.GetType()
}
#-----------------------------------
#END SAMPLE SCRIPT
```

Expected output:

```
ID: 1 , X: 101 , Y: 101 , TYPE: System.Collections.Hashtable
ID: 2 , X: 102 , Y: 102 , TYPE: System.Collections.Hashtable
ID: 3 , X: 103 , Y: 103 , TYPE: System.Collections.Hashtable
ID: 4 , X: 104 , Y: 104 , TYPE: System.Collections.Hashtable
ID: 5 , X: 105 , Y: 105 , TYPE: System.Collections.Hashtable
ID: 128 , X: 128 , Y: 128 , TYPE: System.Collections.Hashtable
ID: 6 , X: 106 , Y: 106 , TYPE: System.Collections.Hashtable
ID: 7 , X: 107 , Y: 107 , TYPE: System.Collections.Hashtable
ID: 8 , X: 108 , Y: 108 , TYPE: System.Collections.Hashtable
ID: 9 , X: 109 , Y: 109 , TYPE: System.Collections.Hashtable
```

Error that I get:

```
Exception calling "AddAfter" with "2" argument(s): 
"The LinkedList node does not belong to current LinkedList."
```

Line that triggers the error message:

```
$list.AddAfter($item, @{ID=128;X=128;Y=128})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically, using `foreach`, you iterate over the values (`hashtable`), and not the `LinkedListNode`, which is what is expected input for `AddAfter` method. I recommend iterating over the list as follows -

```
#BEGIN SAMPLE SCRIPT
#------------------------
$list = New-Object Collections.Generic.LinkedList[Hashtable] 

For($i=1; $i -lt 10; $i++){
   $list.AddLast(@{ID=$i; X=100+$i;Y=100+$i}) 
} 

$current = $list.First

while(-not ($current -eq $null))
{
   If($current.Value.X -eq 105)
   { 
       $list.AddAfter($current, @{ID=128;X=128;Y=128}) 
       Break
   }

   $current = $current.Next
}  

ForEach($item In $list){
   write-host "ID:"$item.ID", X:"$item.x", Y:"$item.y", TYPE:" $item.GetType()
}
#-----------------------------------
#END SAMPLE SCRIPT
```

Comment: Perfect way to iterate though the list.

Comment: Thank you for explaining that; no wonder none of the declarations and castings helped - I was handling the wrong object.

Answer (score 0):

Just to get the mind going I had a look at this. The issue is what the error is suggesting. `$item` is a hashtable and not a linkedlist object. In order to find the correct position in the list I performed a `Find` on the `$item`. Once that was done I got the desired output. Makes me think that there is a better way to crawl through the list.....

```
$list.AddAfter($list.Find($item), @{ID=128;X=128;Y=128})
```

Having a look at the data types of the objects:

```
$item.GetType().FullName
System.Collections.Hashtable


($list.Find($item)).GetType().Fullname
System.Collections.Generic.LinkedListNode`1[[System.Collections.Hashtable, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]
```

It would seem that the position in the LinkedList is not preserved when using `ForEach` hence the need to locate the position with a `Find`

For anyone not familiar with LinkedLists I found [this](http://www.codethinked.com/an-overview-of-system_collections_generic) to be a useful resource.